# Fully qualified class name with @Conditional

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a course video about spring boot and auto-configuration

[image]

It say that we could use a fully qualified class name `type = { "a.b.c.Foo" }` instead of `value = { Foo.class }` if we don't want to depend on the class object at compile time.

Can you explain me what that means ?

Comment: `Foo.class` implies an `import a.b.c.Foo;`, `"a.b.c.Foo"` doesn't. (Note the use of quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `type = { "a.b.c.Foo" }` will compile even if there is no class `a.b.c.Foo` on your classpath, while `value = { a.b.c.Foo.class }` requires `Foo` to be on your classpath at least at compile time. Due to the nature of the annotations both variants can be executed even if `a.b.c.Foo` is not present on the classpath on runtime - at least under some circumstances:

JavaDoc of `@ConditionalOnClass.value`

> Since this annotation is parsed by loading class bytecode, it is safe to specify classes here that may ultimately not be on the classpath, only if this annotation is directly on the affected component and **not** if this annotation is used as a composed, meta-annotation. In order to use this annotation as a meta-annotation, only use the {@link #name} attribute.

In general the `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation can be used to execute configurations that depend on other classes to be present.

For example you could have different Cloud storage configurations AWS, GCP and Azure. Each of these configurations registers a `CloudUpload` bean. And with `@ConditionalOnClass` you execute only the configuration that is currently valid, i.e. if the AWS SDK is on the classpath, you configure the `S3CloudUpload` bean, ...

That is simply by adapting your deployment/classpath you configure your software in a different way.